# Hebrew Calendar View Android Studio

Tags: java, android, calendarview

Hi I am wondering if there was a way to get the Android Calendar View to make a visual of the Hebrew Calendar? I would want the Hebrew months and days as well as the events there. I can put all the information in there, I would just need the structure for the information to display. If the CalendarView does not have this, is there a different easier way to do it?

Thanks

EDIT:

Please note that I do not want this:

[image]

This is the english Calendar in hebrew letters.
I would want the Hebrew Calendar.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/HebrewCalendar.html

Comment: @isaace I saw that, but how would I incorporate that into the CalanderView

Comment: @EdonFreiner did you found solution to show Hebrew Calendar View?